# Theory : is it possible to save circular image?

Tags: image

I'm wondering if it is possible to save circular image or if it always have to be a squared ou rectangular image even if you select a circular ROI?

No specific language, this is more like a theorical question. In order to know which maximale size I can process.

In my case, I apply a circular mask with matlab on a BMP image  and it returns squared images. I don't need the information around the circle and therefore I want to reduce the size of my image to save computational cost for the following processes.

Comment: Any specific programming language, environment or file format ?

Comment: It may differ now but [take a look](http://superuser.com/a/327507/381953).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File formats like PNG or JPG simply do not make sense for a circular image, because *the file formats* already *imply* that there is a rectangular collection of pixels to be stored.

Of course, one *could* define an own file format. There is nothing preventing you from defining a file format, maybe similar to PNG, that additionally stores a radius (in pixels), and beyond that only stores the pixels that are part of the circular region.

Another option is simply a different representation in memory. You could, for example, define a circular region of pixels in memory:

```
  PPPP
 PPPPPP
PPPPPPPP
 PPPPPP
  PPPP
```

Then you could arrange these pixels (in memory!) to fill a rectangular region:

```
PPPP PPPPPP PPPPPPPP
PPPPPP PPPP ........
```

and save this as an image. (Note that the image format has to be lossless. Storing such an image as JPG would not make sense for various reasons). When decoding this image (i.e. when reading the image file), you would additionally need information about the original radius of the circle. Then you could construct a new circular region of pixels, filled with the pixels that have been read from the (rectangular) image.

Something like this *might* even make sense when you have a *very* large circular region, and want to avoid saving the (useless) "corner pixels" in a file. But I doubt that there are *realistic* application cases for something like this.